# If $f(x)g(y)$ is a measurable function, and $f$, $g \in L^{1}(dm)$, does this imply $g(y - x) \in L^{1}(dm)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Question rephrased**

Suppose we are working in $(\mathbb{R}, \Sigma(m^{*}) \times \Sigma(m^{*}), m \times m)$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.  Note that our $\sigma$-algebra is not necessarily complete.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are in $L^{1}(dm)$.  I am trying to understand my analysis notes on convolution, and in one part of the notes, a fact is used that for the functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$, if the product $f(x)g(y -x)$ is measurable, then not only is $g( y -x )$ measurable, but also in $L^{1}(dm)$.  Why?

Comment: What if $g$ is a constant function?

Comment: @QuangHoang What do you mean?  If $g$ is constant and $fg$ is measurable, of course that implies $f$ is measurable.  But I guess I should have specified that neither $f$ nor $g$ are constants.

Comment: Second question: more structure required in $X$.

Comment: If $g$ is constant, then $fg$ is constant, regardless of $f$.

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm confused by what you mean.  Take $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 2$.  $g$ is constant, but $(fg)(x) = 2x$ is not constant.

Comment: Your product is actually composition?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I updated the question.

Comment: Your updated question assumes from the outset that $g \in L^1$. Are you trying to show that $g(y-x)$ is measurable as a function of $x$ for fixed $y$? Or vice versa? Or measurable as a function of $(x,y)$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I want to prove $g(y-x)$ is a measurable function with $x$ fixed.  And after that, I want to show it is also in $L^{1}(dm)$.

Comment: Fix $x$. The function $\phi(y) = y-x$ has an absolutely continuous inverse which preserves measurable sets. Thus if $G$ is an open set then $(g \circ \phi)^{-1}(G)$ is measurable.

Comment: @UmbertoP. What is an absolutely continuous inverse?  Once I get that, I will understand what you are saying.

Comment: Perhaps that is too much. $\phi^{-1}$ is a translation which carries measurable sets to measurable sets.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I don't know how to prove that if $g(y) = y -x$, then $g^{-1}(E)$ is measurable if $E$ is measurable.

Comment: I always thought that in the settings of convolution, $g(y-x)$ is consider as a function of $x$ for a fixed $y$. It doesn't change much of the argument anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not if nonmeasurable sets exist. Let $h$ be a $0-1$ valued nonmeasurable function. The product of $f = h+1$ and $g = 1/f$ is constant, but $f$ is not measurable.

Your second question must take place on some type of group, not an arbitrary measure space.

Comment: Hello, would you mind deleting this answer?  I would like to delete this question and re-ask, but in a much more formulated way.  I can only delete the question if it has only one answer.  Also, this answer is to an earlier version of this question anyway, so it does not add to the rephrased version.  Thanks either way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your two new questions is yes. If you consider $S_f=\{f^{-1}(E)|E\in\Sigma\}$, then if $g(x)=f(-x)$ and $h(x)=f(x+s)$ then we actually have $S_f,S_g,S_h$ are all measurable iff any one of them is. This is because measurable sets remain measurable when rotated or translated, and in fact the measure stays the same under these actions (assuming we are in a place where those operations can be carried out).

In addition to Umberto's example, we have the trivial example where one of the functions is the zero function. There is a bit of ambiguity about if you mean composition or multiplication, as $fg$ can mean either depending on the context, however the zero function is a counterexample for both meanings, and, if composition is intended, then any constant function is.

Comment: Let me try to prove shifting a function preserves measurability.  Is this correct?  If $g(y) = y - x$, then $\{ y \mid g(y) > \alpha \} = \{ y \mid y - x > \alpha \} = \{ y \mid y > \alpha + x \}$, and $h(y) = y$ is measurable, which means $\{ y \mid y > \alpha + x \} \in \Sigma$.

Comment: And clearly, composition of measurable functions is measurable, so therefore, for any measurable function $f(y)$, $f(g(y))$, which represents shifting horizontally by a factor of $x$, is measurable.

Comment: P.S. I always mean multiplication.  In my opinion, using $fg$ for composition is careless, even though a lot of people do it.  I would always write $f \circ g$ or $f(g(y))$ if I mean composition.

Comment: Just a little defense here, I got confused when you write $fg$ following "related questions $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$". But I agree, for (real) functions, $fg$ almost certainly means the product $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: @QuangHoang I know what you are talking about.  In the context of linear functionals, for example, $\Lambda f$ really means $\Lambda(f)$.  But I never write $\Lambda f$ because it's so careless in my opinion.

Comment: That's exactly right. The way my answer is worded one only has to prove that the shift of a measurable set is measurable (which is trivial), but your proof is right, it's not hard.